# Problema con la plantilla de clase vector c++

Tags: c++, array

Buenas noches tengo un lio con un codigo en C++ use la plantilla de clase Vector para ingresar sierto numero de datos dao por el usuario, lo que pasa es que use una funcion para ingresar los datos y otra para mostrar datos, el error o la excepcion me sale al momento de llamar a la funcion mostrarDatos() el siguiente error

esta es la excepcion que me sale

[image]

y este es parte del codigo

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void ingresoDatos(vector <string> nombreEquipo,
                    vector <string> nombreJugador,
                    vector <string> cedula,
                    vector <string> telefono,
                    vector <string> direccion,
                    vector <int> edad,
                    vector <double> estatura,
                    vector <double> costoJugador, int numDatos)//argumentos
{
    string nEquipo;
    string nJugador;
    string ci;
    string tlf;
    string direcc;
    int ed;
    double altura, costo;

    for (int i = 0; i < numDatos; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(20) << " JUGADOR NUMERO" << i + 1 << " : "<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        cin.get();
        cout << "\tNOMBRE DEL EQUIPO : ";
        getline(cin, nEquipo);
        nombreEquipo.push_back(nEquipo);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\tNOMBRE DEL JUGADOR : ";
        getline(cin, nJugador);
        nombreJugador.push_back(nJugador);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\tEDAD : ";
        cin >> ed;
        edad.push_back(ed);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\tESTATURA : ";
        cin >> altura;
        estatura.push_back(altura);
        cout << endl;
        cin.get();
        cout << "\tNUMERO DE IDENTIFICACION : ";
        getline(cin, ci);
        cedula.push_back(ci);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\tNUMERO DE TELEFONO MOVIL: ";
        getline(cin, tlf);
        telefono.push_back(tlf);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\tDIRECCION : ";
        getline(cin, direcc);
        direccion.push_back(direcc);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\tCOSTO DEL JUGADOR (dolares) : ";
        cin >> costo;
        costoJugador.push_back(costo);
        cout << endl;
    }


}

void mostrarDatos(vector <string> nombreEquipo,
    vector <string> nombreJugador,
    vector <string> cedula,
    vector <string> telefono,
    vector <string> direccion,
    vector <int> edad,
    vector <double> estatura,
    vector <double> costoJugador, int numDatos)
{
    cout << numDatos;
    cin.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < numDatos; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(20) << " JUGADOR NUMERO" << i + 1 << " : " << endl;
        cout << "NOMBRE DEL EQUIPO : " << nombreEquipo.at(i) << endl;
        cout << "NOMBRE DEL JUGADOR : " << nombreJugador.at(i) << endl;
        cout << "EDAD : " << edad.at(i) << endl;
        cout << "ESTATURA : " << estatura.at(i) << endl;
        cout << "IDENTIFICACION : " << cedula.at(i) << endl;
        cout << "TELEFONO : " << telefono.at(i) << endl;
        cout << "DIRECCION : " << direccion.at(i) << endl;
        cout << "VALOR EN EL MERCADO : " << costoJugador.at(i) << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    vector <string> nombreEquipo;
    vector <string> nombreJugador;
    vector <string> cedula;
    vector <string> telefono;
    vector <string> direccion;
    vector <int> edad;
    vector <double> estatura;
    vector <double> costoJugador;
    int numDatos;

    cout << "Cuantos datos va a ingresar" << endl;
    cin >> numDatos;
    cout << endl;
    ingresoDatos(nombreEquipo, nombreJugador, cedula, telefono,
                direccion, edad, estatura, costoJugador, numDatos);
    cout << endl;
    mostrarDatos(nombreEquipo, nombreJugador, cedula, telefono,
                direccion, edad, estatura, costoJugador, numDatos);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal error que tienes es causado por no entender que la función `ingresoDatos()` le estas pasando los vectores por valor, es decir los vectores que estan en el main son distintos a los vectores que estan en dicha función, una forma de solucionar podria ser pasarlos por referencia pero en este caso yo lo veo innecesario. Por ejemplo tus vectores en main tienen tamaño 0, al terminar de ejecutarse la función ingresoDatos() seguiran teniendo tamaño 0 ya que has rellenado otros vectores, por lo que al imprimir estas asumiendo que tienen un tamaño distinto de 0 accediendo a memoria no reservada y generandote ese problema.

Otro problema es que estas creando muchos vectores, y este es un problema de diseño, la idea es que crees una struct que guarde la información de un solo elemento, y entonces crees un vector de esos elementos.

Por ultimo para saber el tamaño de un vector debes usar la funcion `size()`.

Un mejor enfoque es que la función ingresoDatos() solo tenga como entrada el número de datos, y como salida el vector, la función mostrarDatos() debe de tener como entrada el vector y no es necesario numDatos ya que para ello se usara la función size():

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

struct Datos{
    std::string nombreEquipo;
    std::string nombreJugador;
    std::string cedula;
    std::string telefono;
    std::string direccion;
    int edad;
    double estatura;
    double costoJugador;
};

std::vector<Datos> ingresoDatos(size_t numDatos)//argumentos
{
    std::vector<Datos> datos;
    std::string nEquipo, nJugador,ci, tlf, direcc;
    int ed;
    double altura, costo;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numDatos; i++)
    {
        Datos dato;
        std::cout << std::setw(20) << " JUGADOR NUMERO" << i + 1 << " : "<<"\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cin.get();
        std::cout << "\tNOMBRE DEL EQUIPO : ";
        getline(std::cin, nEquipo);
        dato.nombreEquipo = nEquipo;
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tNOMBRE DEL JUGADOR : ";
        getline(std::cin, nJugador);
        dato.nombreJugador = nJugador;
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tEDAD : ";
        std::cin >> ed;
        dato.edad = ed;
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tESTATURA : ";
        std::cin >> altura;
        dato.estatura = altura;
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cin.get();
        std::cout << "\tNUMERO DE IDENTIFICACION : ";
        getline(std::cin, ci);
        dato.cedula = ci;
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tNUMERO DE TELEFONO MOVIL: ";
        getline(std::cin, tlf);
        dato.telefono = tlf;
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tDIRECCION : ";
        getline(std::cin, direcc);
        dato.direccion = direcc;
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tCOSTO DEL JUGADOR (dolares) : ";
        std::cin >> costo;
        dato.costoJugador = costo;
        std::cout << "\n";
        datos.push_back(dato);
    }
    return datos;
}

void mostrarDatos(std::vector <Datos> datos)
{
    std::cin.get();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++)
    {
        Datos dato = datos.at(i);
        std::cout << std::setw(20) << " JUGADOR NUMERO" << i + 1 << " : " << "\n";
        std::cout << "NOMBRE DEL EQUIPO : " << dato.nombreEquipo << "\n";
        std::cout << "NOMBRE DEL JUGADOR : " << dato.nombreJugador << "\n";
        std::cout << "EDAD : " << dato.edad << "\n";
        std::cout << "ESTATURA : " << dato.estatura << "\n";
        std::cout << "IDENTIFICACION : " << dato.cedula << "\n";
        std::cout << "TELEFONO : " << dato.telefono << "\n";
        std::cout << "DIRECCION : " << dato.direccion << "\n";
        std::cout << "VALOR EN EL MERCADO : " << dato.costoJugador << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    size_t numDatos;
    std::cout << "Cuantos datos va a ingresar" << "\n";
    std::cin >> numDatos;
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::vector<Datos> datos = ingresoDatos(numDatos);
    std::cout << "\n";
    mostrarDatos(datos);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Actualización:**

Si no deseas usar structs entonces deberias pasar los valores por referencia y para ello cambia tu código inicial a:

```
void ingresoDatos(vector<string> & nombreEquipo,
                  vector<string> & nombreJugador,
                  vector<string> & cedula,
                  vector<string> & telefono,
                  vector<string> & direccion,
                  vector<int> & edad,
                  vector<double> & estatura,
                  vector<double> & costoJugador, int numDatos)//argumentos
```

Comment: Gracias de hecho si lo veía así usar un struct pero en la clase que sigo aún no vemos structs por eso le hice asi, hay alguna solución para hacer el programa sin necesidad de estructuras, y otra cuando pongo toda la parte de código que está en mostrardatos() en ingresardatos() y elimino la función mostrarDatos() ahí si me funciona todo el programa es decir puedo ingresar y se imprime los datos

Comment: @ErikAndres mira mi actualizacion

Comment: @ErikAndres si mi respuesta te ayudo no olvides marcarla como correcta, si no sabes como hacerlo revisa el [tour], esa es la mejor forma de agradecer :)

Comment: Si hago esto.                std::vector <int *> datos.  Es un arreglo de punteros ?

Comment: Creo que me mal entendiste no voy a usar eso en el programa que tengo,  solo era una duda muy a parte

Comment: @ErikAndres `std::vector<int *> datos` es un vector de punteros, un array y un vector son 2 conceptos distintos, ademas esta sección no es para discutir temas externos a la pregunta, gana reputación y podras ingresar al chat donde este tipo de preguntas son bienvenidas

Comment: @ErikAndres por favor pasa el [tour], lee [ask] para que conozca la dinámica de SO para que todas tus consultas sean bienvenidas en el lugar correcto :)